# Using a series of attenuators for a sampling HF transmission math or design errors/misunderstand/ignorance

Tags: circuit-design, rf, impedance-matching, ham-radio, attenuator

TLDR: Why does my math not work.
SITUATION: I have a 1.5KW 50 ohm RF dummy load for ham radio and I'm trying to design a sample port for monitoring with a spectrum analyzer. I have now realized that there are probably better methods for accomplishing this task.  Simple capacitive coupling isn't really suitable as I would like a reasonably flat attenuation curve from 1.8Mhz to 100Mhz.  I'm trying to be a good radio operator and get accurate numbers on higher harmonic spurs. I designed this about 6 months ago and had to walk away due to not understanding what is wrong, I've revisited it many times since then looking for what I don't understand.

PLAN: Embed the attenuator into the oil filled dummy load.  Design with a series of 3 PI attenuators while lowering the impedance through each stage for 2 reasons.  One is to minimize any change in impedance to the existing 50 ohms of the dummy load.  Second is to minimize the power dissipation in the attenuator.  Here is what I learned from  [Matching Pi Attenuators](https://chemandy.com/calculators/matching-pi-attenuator-calculator.htm) I have found other sites agreeing. I wrote a spreadsheet and verified it generates the same results per stage as the online calc. I then simulated the results in Kicad and results were way less at output than calculated.  I then did a DC analysis by hand, I got the same answer as Kicad's sim.

I can't upload the spreadsheet here is a screen shot. I'm glad to share it if someone tells me how.  Green boxes are inputs. Total power in, input and output impedance of each stage and the db attenuation of each stage. Resistor values are calculated with power dissipation. These numbers match for online calcs. Power figures have to be invalid as the Vpp calc at each stage is incorrect.

[image: Spreadsheet]
I get about 8mVpp output, spreadsheet says 774mVpp.
As a test, I modified the circuit an changed R100 to 1 ohm, disabled R3 and R6 and only get 140mVpp output.  R9 would be the 50 ohms of the spectrum analyzer.
[image: Kicad sim circuit]

Obviously I completely misunderstand something here. Please someone explain why this doesn't calculate so I can sleep again. lol
Thanks
Cory

Comment: At 100 MHz, and well below it, those 100kohm values are simply unrealisable. There's a reason RF systems are designed around 50 ohms, and don't use resistor values that are more than an order of magnitude away from that. It may be a 1500 W load, but what power do you actually want to operate up to?

Comment: I'm allowed an to transmit 1500W, this amp is 600W, but I have not ruled out a larger amp.  I know i would end up using a string of 10K resistors and possibly SMD to minimize the effects of their capacitance and inductance.  I didn't realize their was a hard limit of 50 ohms and was taught that was partly due to coax being in that region, and so is a 1/2 dipole.  But I use 450 ohm and have used 600 ohm ladder line.  2K ohm filters, and tube grids are pretty high impedance.  I'm probably using a torrid core as a pickup after more research.  But the question was what is my downfall in the math?

Comment: Are your 8 mV and 140 mV measured or simulated? So, are your numbers wrong, or the physical implementation? At 100 MHz, you should still be able to make a reasonable wideband transmission line transformer for picking off lower powers. You might want to consider other attenuator topologies. Waveguide beyond cutoff is one, and reconsider capacitive input/output, if you use an output C low enough to drive 50 ohms. However, a series string of several 10s of K at several watts each, straight into the 50 ohm of a line to your spec ana is what I would do. I do that at GHz, though not kW!

Comment: The 8 mV is simulated, it also works out the same with basic DC circuit analysis just reducing the circuit down.  I have done that once, not sure with these values, but the simulator matched the math.  The problem with the capacitance sampler is it exaggerates high order harmonics.  I don't think it's possible that this old tube amp is outputting 28.5 Mhz and 280 Mhz only 25db down.  I have checked the spreadsheet against the online calculator for each section.  If I input 61.7dbm and attenuate 25&20&15 with the impedance matched for each stage should I not get 1.7dbm out?  This is my stress!

Comment: A resistor of apparent value 100 kohm might have 0.5 pF parasitic capacitance. At 100 MHz 0.5 pF has an impedance of just over 3 kohm thus ruining any controlled attenuation based on resistor values. My advice: design the dummy load to also be an attenuator.

Comment: Yes, I do agree this is not the best circuit for this design.  The underlying question is what was my misconception or error in the math.  The spreadsheet has been checked against online calcs, but the total attenuation doesn't add up.

Comment: @CoryLytle A capacitve sampler can be flat, you make a C to C attenuator, see my comment, use an output C low enough to drive 50 ohms. Any 10:1 scope probe is a flat capacitive divider for most of the bandwidth, only using its resistor to control things in the DC-kHz range.

Comment: @CoryLytle sorry to inform that every on-line calculator I've ever seen (including the one you linked) won't calculate the resistor values correctly when the input impedance and the output impedance are different values. They all seem to have been copied from some "ancestor" website (god knows which one) that has a basic error carried through to them all. For this reason I made my own website calculator but, it uses a T attenuator (aka a taper pad attenuator) rather than a pi section attenuator. I will get round to making a pi attenuator that does the job correctly but not this year it seems!

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you! This is the information I needed, I have found peace. Could you point me to the correct formulas?

Comment: @Neil_UK  The second C, duh.  Now I get it. Thanks!

Comment: I only have formulas for a T pad attenuator. @CoryLytle

Comment: @Andyaka could you share those?

Comment: http://stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Taper%20pad%20attenuator.html <-- if it plus a few words constitutes an acceptable answer for this site, please let me know @CoryLytle

Comment: @Andyaka I consider the online reference to be wrong as the answer to the question.  The issue that I could not get calculations to match the real world outcome by a huge factor was the issue I was having, I'm not that bad at math.  Thanks, again

Comment: Which on line reference do you refer to, mine or the other. How so you want to deal with this question not having a formal answer?

Comment: The link in my original post. I don't have an accept answer button. How do I do that?

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you so much.  I finally got back into this and built my ladder spreadsheet with your formulas.  The math and the simulation agree with it.  I still don't know how to accept your answer.  I left an answer at the bottom. If you want to write one I will accept it. Online calcs are wrong, I didn't go crazy! lol. Thanks again.

Comment: You can accept your own answer; you've done some hard work proving my web site formula so you should have the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that @Andyaka has discovered that many online attenuator calculators do not give proper results when the input and output impedance are not equal. I'm accepting this as the answer since they don't seem to work in real life circuits